# What is the difference between stubs and mocks in the context of test spy? (jasmine)

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I was reading this document [sinonjs.org](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) and to me is not clear the different between stubs and mocks.
Could someone explain me with simple words and some example the difference between stubs and mocks?

P.S.:
I already read about [What is the difference between mocks and stubs ( JMock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764981/what-is-the-difference-between-mocks-and-stubs-jmock), but the answers have no examples.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain in a few words:

- mock: use it if you are going to verify a collaboration in your SUT. You have to mock the collaborator and then verify if the collaboration is done.

  ```
  var collaborator = {};
  collaborator.collaboration = sinon.mock();
  SUT.setCollaborator(collaborator);
  SUT.play();
  collaborator.collaboration.verify();
  ```
- stub: use it if you need a collaborator fot your SUT, but the test is not testing the collaboration.

  ```
  var collaborator = {};
  collaborator.collaboration = sinon.stub().returns(1);
  SUT.setCollaborator(collaborator);
  SUT.play();
  ```

The technology underneath stubs and mocks is similar, the difference is the intention of the test.

From http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks:

> Mocks come with built-in expectations that may fail your test. Thus,
>   they enforce implementation details. The rule of thumb is: if you
>   wouldn't add an assertion for some call specific, don't mock it. Use a
>   stub instead.

Answer (score 2):

Below important notes will help you to understand the exact difference between Spies, Stubs and Mocks:

- **Spies**, which offer information about function calls, without affecting their behavior
- **Stubs**, which are like spies, but completely replace the function. This makes it possible 
  to make a stubbed function do whatever you like — throw an exception, return a specific 
  value, etc
- **Mocks**, which make replacing whole objects easier by combining both spies and stubs